# Prevent search bots from indexing server (sub)domain name

Tags: search-engines, subdomain, webserver, nginx

A web application I wrote is hosted on an in-house server with the name `myserver`, which is under my university's domain (`department.uni.edu`), resulting in the server's address being `myserver.department.uni.edu`. When I Google *myserver*, the first result is that exact server hosting the web application.

I have a **robots.txt** file for the application (root directory) with the following contents:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

It's the actual server *domain name* that was indexed, and not anything in the web application.

I know that I can remove search results with [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home), but **how do I prevent Google from indexing a server's *domain name*** (or *address*)? I believe the server is running Nginx on Ubuntu 14.10 (I am not the person in charge of the server, just coding the web application).

The desire here is to prevent the server from being indexed by web searching tools such as Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc. - basically block all known search engine crawlers.

Perhaps a solution is to block all crawlers to the subdomain's root (`mysever.department.university.edu`) using an Nginx rewrite rule such as:

```
map $http_user_agent $limit_bots {
     default 0;
     ~*(google|bing|yandex|msnbot) 1;
     ~*(AltaVista|Googlebot|Slurp|BlackWidow|Bot|ChinaClaw|Custo|DISCo|Download|Demon|eCatch|EirGrabber|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|SuperHTTP|Surfbot|WebWhacker) 1;
     ~*(Express|WebPictures|ExtractorPro|EyeNetIE|FlashGet|GetRight|GetWeb!|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It|GrabNet|Grafula|HMView|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It) 1;
     ~*(rafula|HMView|HTTrack|Stripper|Sucker|Indy|InterGET|Ninja|JetCar|Spider|larbin|LeechFTP|Downloader|tool|Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|tAkeOut|WWWOFFLE) 1;
     ~*(GrabNet|NetSpider|Vampire|NetZIP|Octopus|Offline|PageGrabber|Foto|pavuk|pcBrowser|RealDownload|ReGet|SiteSnagger|SmartDownload|SuperBot|WebSpider) 1;
     ~*(Teleport|VoidEYE|Collector|WebAuto|WebCopier|WebFetch|WebGo|WebLeacher|WebReaper|WebSauger|eXtractor|Quester|WebStripper|WebZIP|Wget|Widow|Zeus) 1;
     ~*(Twengabot|htmlparser|libwww|Python|perl|urllib|scan|Curl|email|PycURL|Pyth|PyQ|WebCollector|WebCopy|webcraw) 1;
 }

location / {
    if ($limit_bots = 1) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

([borrowed from GD Hussle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24820722/1986871))

but, would this be sufficient or would something more sophisticated be necessary?

Comment: The robots.txt file should do it. Just make sure that it is in the web root and can be read okay. It may be that someone linked to your site? If this is the case, Google will list it with a SERP link only and a notation that the site description is not available. Google should not do this, but they do. Otherwise, you can block access and do a full HTTP request drop instead of a 404 or a 410. This is typically done in a firewall or you can possibly use ModSecurity or other web application firewall.

Comment: When you find your server's name does it say "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more."? I don't think you can make Google not index the domain name itself.

Comment: @barrycarter This is exactly correct. The problem is that the root URL for the server is where the web application is hosted, meaning though the web app isn't indexed itself, the server subdomain which is indexed is pointing to the web application! Now, the server could rewrite the URL to `myserver.department.uni.edu/webapp`, and have the root return some other *thing*, but that would break every existing URL. And we can't break URLs, because redirecting would make it so Google would again point to the web application. Very frustrating...

Comment: @closetnoc The robots.txt file is definitely being read correctly (see *barrycarter*'s comment). Since I don't manage the server: just doing basic Googling, would [configuring Nginx to respond with an HTTP 444](http://ghost.thekindof.me/dropping-http-requests-and-connection-efficiently-on-nginx) for the subdomain root URL (***if the user agent is a bot***) be sufficient to prevent its indexing on search engines? Basically, if Google/other bots crawl `myserver.department.uni.edu`, I want to drop the connection for them, but allow non-bots to connect successfully.

Comment: I just got back in. A 404 error will say that a particular page is Temporarily Gone while a 410 will say that a particular page is Gone. Either should work okay except that a 404 takes longer. That would be fine. But I am not sure that Google will stop trying to access the sub-domain per se' as long as a web server is responding with a response code. A 404 or 410 is on a page by page basis. I was suggesting, and only if it was easy to do, was to make it appear that the server was gone. ;-) Stick with the 404!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With robots.txt you can control *crawling*, not *indexing*. If a search engine is not allowed to crawl a document on your host, it might still index its URL, e.g. if it found the link on an external site.

You can control indexing with the `meta`-`robots` element or the `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP header ([see examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34925637/1591669)).

You have to decide if you want to allow search engines to crawl but not to index, or to index but not to crawl. Because if you disallow crawling in robots.txt, search engines won’t be able to reach your documents, so they’ll never learn that you don’t want these to get indexed.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, I can't possibly drop HTTP requests into the root URL because then crawlers can't read `robots.txt`, meaning that anything linked in the site would be likely to turn up in search results? So it would essentially be impossible to disallow indexing of the root url?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: Not sure I understand. --- If you don’t want the root URL to get *indexed*, you could send the HTTP header: `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` (which, of course, only works for the search engines that support it). For this to work, your robots.txt must allow crawling of the root URL (otherwise bots would never see the HTTP header).

Comment: I want to 1. prevent indexing of the site's root URL (the server domain `myserver.department.university.edu`) and 2. any of the site's contents in `myserver.department.university.edu/`. I mentioned earlier writing an Nginx rule to drop HTTP requests if the request was to the root URL; but, if I did that then crawlers wouldn't be able to read `robots.txt`, if I understand your answer. Meaning that I can't do **both** of my desired things. I am already preventing indexing of anything past `/`, but I don't want the server's domain to be in search results either. It seems that I can't do both.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: I think we are talking about different things.  If you disallow **crawling** of your site (in robots.txt), you can’t disallow **indexing** of your site. But if you are fine with bots crawling your site, you can disallow indexing (= bots can look around, but are not allowed to list the URLs in their search results). -- With "dropping", you mean sending a 403 instead of 200, right? But this wouldn’t change anything regarding indexing (while some bots might not *want* to index 403’d documents, they would still be "allowed" to).

Comment: Unor, correct, responding to HTTP requests (based on `User-Agent` as in my suggested Nginx solution in the question) at the root url of `myserver.department.university.edu/`. The idea is to not have the server's contents show up in search engine results. Bots can crawl all they want, they won't find any useful resources because they are all protected by login - the server will serve `HTTP 403`. I don't mind crawling, as long as **nothing** on the site, including the server's root url, is viewable in search engine results. Does that make sense? Sorry, I lack the necessary terminology!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: Then I’d suggest to allow crawling of each page in the robots.txt, and send `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` for each page. Conforming bots may visit your pages, but may not list the URLs to these pages.

Comment: Unor, that sounds like a good idea. Would you say that most popular search engines are "conforming bots"? People can *find* the URL, but I'd rather they not by conventional search engines such as Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: It’s supported [by Bing](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-can-i-remove-a-url-or-page-from-the-bing-index-37c07477), [by Google Search](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=en#using-the-x-robots-tag-http-header), and [by Yahoo](http://www.ysearchblog.com/2007/12/05/yahoo-search-support-for-x-robots-tag-directive-to-simplify-webmasters-control-and-weather-update/). But, for example, [DuckDuckGo doesn’t seem to support it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18108618/1591669).

Comment: Alright Unor, I'll give that a shot. Sorry for the long discussion; I have no experience in search engines and indexing aside from `robots.txt`. Preventing major search providers from listing the site should be sufficient for my purposes!